# Parse JSON to multiple Typescript objects

Tags: json, typescript, parsing

I know that there are already multiple questions about parsing JSON files in Typescript, but non of these helped me.

I'm trying to parse the result of the license-checker output which is a json:

```
{
  "@angular/core@10.1.4": {
    "licenses": "MIT",
    "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular",
    "publisher": "angular",
    "name": "@angular/core",
    "version": "10.1.4",
    "description": "Angular - the core framework",
    "licenseFile": "C:\\Users\\UC190\\workspace\\core-search-app\\node_modules\\@angular\\core\\README.md",
    "licenseText": "Angular\n=======\n\nThe sources for this package are in the main [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular) repo. Please file issues and pull requests against that repo.\n\nUsage information and reference details can be found in [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs).\n\nLicense: MIT",
    "path": "C:\\Users\\UC190\\workspace\\core-search-app\\node_modules\\@angular\\core"
  },
  "@angular/forms@10.1.4": {
    "licenses": "MIT",
    "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular",
    "publisher": "angular",
    "name": "@angular/forms",
    "version": "10.1.4",
    "description": "Angular - directives and services for creating forms",
    "licenseFile": "C:\\Users\\UC190\\workspace\\core-search-app\\node_modules\\@angular\\forms\\README.md",
    "licenseText": "Angular\n=======\n\nThe sources for this package are in the main [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular) repo. Please file issues and pull requests against that repo.\n\nUsage information and reference details can be found in [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs).\n\nLicense: MIT",
    "path": "C:\\Users\\UC190\\workspace\\core-search-app\\node_modules\\@angular\\forms"
  },
  ...
}
```

Therefore I created an interface to parse the elements:

```
export interface JsonData {
  licenses: string;
  repository: string;
  publisher: string;
  name: string;
  version: string;
  description: string;
  licenseFile: string;
  licenseText: string;
  path: string;
}
```

But I am struggling on how to iterate over the elements and parse them to a list of `JsonData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces in TypeScript allow you to describe the shape of your data structure (though, that's not their only purpose). In your case, the data structure is a map, keyed on the package name, with a corresponding value which is package/license details.

Consider the following interfaces...

```js
interface Package {
  licenses: string;
  repository: string;
  publisher: string;
  name: string;
  version: string;
  description: string;
  licenseFile: string;
  licenseText: string;
  path: string;
}

interface PackageMap {
  [key:string]: Package
}
```

You can test that you can obtain keys, and their corresponding values with the following...

```js
const data: PackageMap = JSON.parse(json); // Assume json refers to your data structure
const keys: string[] = Object.keys(data);

keys.forEach(key => console.log(key, data[key]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out how to handle this.

I can iterate over the Object, that contains values by

```
for (const value of Object.values(data)) {
  this.dataSource.data.push(this.encodeLicenseData(value));
}
```

And parse the value to what I need in the `encodeLicenseData()` function.